# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'infile' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, file, operation

I am having difficulties tracing an error in my code. Getting a "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'infile' referenced before assignment" error all the time I enter a file name that do not exist.

```
def spam():
    fname = input('Enter the file name: ')
    try:
        infile = open(fname, 'r')
    except:
        print('File cannot be opened:', fname)
        exit
    count = 0
    total = 0
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith('X-DSPAM-Confidence'):
            nam = line.find('0')
            numb = float(line[nam:])
            total = total + numb
            count = count + 1
    print('Average spam confidence:',total/count)
    infile.close()
```

Comment: Where is `exit` defined? MCVE please.

Comment: @user202729 `exit` is just the standard exit command that you would call via `exit()`.

Comment: Well, yes, what else do you expect it to do? If the question was "why doesn't the program stop after printing the message", then that's what you should ask - but then you just have a typo. If the question is "why does the program do wrong things when it continues past the point where it was supposed to stop", well... I don't understand how you could expect otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

you entered the exception, then the program continue to execute, but variable `infile` is not defined.

exit should be used in this way, I didn't test, but replace exit with this:

```
import sys

sys.exit(1)
```

Well, I tested, don't use exit, use `return` solved your problem

Comment: Or without importing sys, if that for whatever reason is beneficial: `raise SystemExit`